# read fields that created dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I learned that how to dynamically add input fields to a form by using [jquery append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append).
My question is: How can read these fields? for example: I want from my visitor to enter a number and I for each number create an input, how read it when I don't know about name of fields and number of them?
And an important problem is how can I naming them. please help me

Comment: This question will probably receive negative votes if you don't include code samples. An example posted to http://www.jsfiddle.net would be ideal.

Comment: When you are adding for example 5 input to your form, how are you naming them?

Comment: you add the property name to them.

Comment: I edit my question, @koopajah I don't know naming, it's my problem

Comment: Are you asking how to read the parameters in PHP since you don't know the names since they are dynamically created? Show the code you have so far and we can help you refine it.

Comment: I give my answer please see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do naming and reading fields that create dynamically
these is your answer:

```
<div>
     <input type="radio" id="radio_1" name="radio1" value="1" /> 1<br />
</div>
```

and in Js:

```
for(i=2;i<=8;i++){
    $("div")
        .append($("#radio_1")
        .clone().attr({"id":"radio_"+i,"value":i}))
        .append(" "+i+"<br />");
}
$(":radio").click(function() {
    var radioID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("by selector (:radio): " + radioID);
});

$("input[name=radio1]").click(function() {
    var radioID2 = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("by groupname: " + radioID2);
});
```

you and commentators can see it [in jsfeedle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFkC7/3/)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say without seeing the code exactly but say it's something like

`$('body').append('<input type="text" class="readMe">');`

You could grab the values of those with something like this:

```
$('.readMe').each(function(){
$(this).val();
});
```